# For every $\Bbb R$-valued random variable $X$ and $\epsilon > 0$, $P (X \neq Y ) <\epsilon$ for some bounded random variable $Y$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Here is the question:
Suppose $X$ is a $\Bbb R$-valued random variable. Show that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a bounded random variable $Y$ such that $P (X \neq Y ) <\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $Y=X\,\mathbf 1_{|X|\leqslant x}$ for $x$ large enough. Then $\mathbb P(Y\ne X)=\mathbb P(|X|\gt x)$. Furthermore, $\mathbb P(|X|\gt x)\to0$ when $x\to+\infty$, hence for $x$ large enough, $Y$ solves the question.

Comment: I presume that $P(X=Y)$ in the question is a typo and should read $P(X\ne Y)$.

Comment: What about the part {X>x}. Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand the question in your comment. If *explain a little bit more* means *provide a full solution one can hand as it is to one's teacher*, the answer is *no*. Otherwise, please explain the part you do not understand.

Comment: It's obviously Y can cover $X\,1_{\left|X\right|\leq x}$ for arbitrary
x. But how do you deal with the part $X\,1_{\left|X\right|>x}$? How
can it be less than any positive number when you fix a x? Thanks!

Comment: *Cover*? *The part*? *Fix* $x$? See the expanded version of my answer.

Comment: That's correct. I misunderstood the question. I thought I should find a Y for all all ε>0, P(X≠Y)<ε.

Comment: @Did would you explain what do you mean by stating $1_{|X| \le x}$

Comment: @PhilJones https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: @Did would you give a brief explanation on how Y = $X 1_{|X| \le x}$ is a bounded random variable... I'm having a bit of difficulty in understanding so...

Comment: @PhilJones For every $\omega$, $|Y(\omega)|\leqslant x$.

Comment: @Did Yeppp, now understood.